# Mongoose: How to query field in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a document that has array of questions, I want each time I submit button the function is run that request next question in the array of question, basically its quiz app where I want to show questions from database that is saved in the document and all questions are saved in the array

Is it right the way I structured data i.e all question in an array and in single document

My question is how can I retrieve each question in the array that is saved in single document, I did something like this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
question : []
})
var quizz = mongoose.model('Quiz', schema );

var firstDoc = new quizz({
question: ['question 1', 'question 2', 'question 3', 'question 4']
})

firstDoc.save(function(err, res){
 if(err){
   console.log("error occured while saving document object " + err )
 }else{
   console.log("saved data");
 }
})
```

should I have to make some ID to identify each question in array so that I can pull question based on ID or this is right what I'm doing

Comment: What is the question? Hard to understand what you need.

Comment: Do you need to find the document for example with `question 1` in the array?

Comment: Yes, also i dont know if i have made the structure right like all the questions in single document in an array

Comment: I have only document that has all the questions in the array

Comment: And i want to retrieve a single question each time i make request from array

Answer (score 0):

To look at documents with specific value in the array you have to use `$in`:

```
quizz.findOne({ question: {$in: ['question 1'] }, function (err, doc) {
   console.log(doc);
});
```

A correct schema for your purpose should be like this:

```
var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   question: String
});
```

Then you can use the schema to create **a document for each question** you have.

```
var firstQuestion = new quizz({
   question: 'question 1'
});
var secondQuestion = new quizz({
   question: 'question 2'
});
```

etc...

Comment: How can I identify 'question 1' like the question 1 is the whole question of multiple lines so I have to write whole question when querying?

Comment: Why do you have a schema like that? I'd like to have a question per document not an array of questions in a single document.

Comment: What would be structure

Comment: should I save each document like if there are 10 document for question I have to save 10 times? and how would I will retrieve? based on?